# How to concisely represent if/else to specify CSS classes in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In a Django template, I'd like to add CSS classes to a DIV based on certain "conditions", for example:

```
<div class="pkg-buildinfo 
            {% if v.release.version == pkg.b.release.version %}active{% else %}inactive{% endif %} 
            {% if v.release.version == project.latest.version %}latest{% else %}notlatest{% endif %}">
```

(*note* that `v` is a loop variable; the whole thing is inside a `for` loop)

The above adds CSS classes "active" or "inactive" and "latest" or "notlatest" based on two conditions.

This is however hard to read and verbose. I discovered that the [`with` statement](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) does not support assigning the value of expressions/conditions (as opposed to complex variables) which is a pity. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @jammon - thanks for the edit, but - are multiline strings supported in HTML attribute values?

Comment: Oh, good point! I have to look that up.

Answer (score 6):

You could put that logic into your view instead, and create attributes on the object that are "active" or "inactive", etc.  Then you only have to access the attributes in the template.

Answer (score 6):

A custom filter might be a nice alternative.

```
@register.filter
def active_class(obj, pkg):
    if obj.release.version == pkg.b.release.version:
         return 'active'
    else:
        return 'inactive'
```

and use it in your template:

```
<div class="pkg-buildinfo {{ obj|active_class:pkg }}"
```

Comment: Might come as a surprise when reading my code a year later ("need to look at a place other than views and templates?" ... "why is 'active_class' not a method of the `obj` class?"), but otherwise good.

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten it a bit by the with statement:

```
{% with v.release.version as version %}
<div class="pkg-buildinfo 
            {% if version == pkg.b.release.version %}active{% else %}inactive{% endif %} 
            {% if version == project.latest.version %}latest{% else %}notlatest{% endif %}">
{% endwith %}
```

But it surely would be better to put that logic into the view:

```
context_data = {
    'class_active': v.release.version == pkg.b.release.version and "active" or "inactive",
    'class_latest': v.release.version == project.latest.version and "latest" or "notlatest",
    ... }
```

and in the template:

```
<div class="pkg-buildinfo {{ class_active }} {{ class_latest }}"
```

Comment: That would have to be v.class_active (`v` is a loop variable) instead of class_active.