# Add active class to element according to URL Jquery Django

Tags: jquery, css, django

How can i add an "active" class to the element according to href

I have a django template like this:

```
<div class="panel side-panel-1 category">
<h4 class="title1">Разделы</h4>
<ul class="clear-list">
{% for section in sections %}
    <li>
        <a href="/advert/adverts.aspx&sec{{ section.id }}">{{ section.name }}  ({{ section.advert_set.count }})</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So the urls will be formed from the `section.id`

### EXAMPLE:

- mysite.com/advert/adverts.aspx&sec1

### in some cases it could be:

- mysite.com/advert/adverts.aspx&sec1&cat10&page1

Comment: When you want to add active class on element ?.  As per my knowledge you can handle it using django conditioning itself.

Comment: I don't know about this function in django. If you you may answer it

Comment: I mean just use normal if condition to check for href and add active class if condition satisfied. refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584426/how-to-concisely-represent-if-else-to-specify-css-classes-in-django-templates

Comment: @Prasad I saw this question, but i can not implement it in my case, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in views.py

```
def adverts_sec(request, advert_sec):
args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['adverts'] =  Advert.objects.filter(advert_section_id=advert_sec).order_by('-advert_date', '-id')
args['sections'] = AdvertSection.objects.all().order_by('-name')
args['categs'] = AdvertCategory.objects.all().order_by('-name')
args['current_section'] = AdvertSection.objects.get(id=advert_sec)
args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
args['reg_form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
return render_to_response('adverts_sec.html', args)
```

and then in template:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    <li class="{% if section.id == current_section.id %}
                    active
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}">
        <a href="/advert/adverts.aspx&sec{{ section.id }}">{{ section.name }}  ({{ section.advert_set.count }})</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

so if we have "current_section" then django compare it to the {{ section.id }} the matched one will gain an 'active' class

Thank you for every one who helped me

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to do this. Only to use `class="{{ section.id ? 'active' : '' }}"`. if the section.id exists, the active wile be add.

```
<div class="panel side-panel-1 category">
<h4 class="title1">Разделы</h4>
<ul class="clear-list">
{% for section in sections %}
    <li class="{{ section.id ? 'active' : '' }}" >
        <a href="/advert/adverts.aspx&sec{{ section.id }}">{{     section.name }}  ({{ section.advert_set.count }})</a>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: **TemplateSyntaxError at /advert/adverts.aspx**

Could not parse the remainder: ' ? 'active' : ''' from 'section.id ? 'active' : '''

Comment: sorry about that, python don't have '?'  operation. You can change to `'active' if section.id else ''`

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: ' if section.id else ''' from ''active' if section.id else '''